# adding action bar to map - AppBarLayout error

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add contextual action bar menu to my GoogleMap activity but it shows error. I've already tried to search numerous questions but I've had no luck 
Hera is logcat output:

```
Process: com.example.lowrider.myapplication, PID: 4143
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lowrider.myapplication/com.example.lowrider.myapplication.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

Here is my .xml layout file for this activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.lowrider.myapplication.MapsActivity">



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:text="Štart"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:text="pridaj"
    android:id="@+id/marker"
    android:onClick="pridaj_bod"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:text="snapshot"
    android:id="@+id/snapshot"
    android:onClick="snapshot"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
```